# SQL to move date from one column to another

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to write a SQL statement for the following. I need to move data in a table from one column to another as follows. The date of `Prior Year` needs to go into the `Current Year` column for prior year dates. The table has 1 Million rows.

If the date is Jan 1, 2017, Location Georgia, Product Distillate, my Current Year Volumes are showing as null. These volumes are sitting in the Jan 1 2018 row as Prior Year Volumes. So I need to move these volumes from 2018 date to 2017 date. The volumes 100 and 200 should move.

My original table looks like this:

```
Date,       Location,   Product,        PY volumes,   CY Volumes

Jan 1 2017, Georgia,    Gasoline,       NULL,           NULL

Jan 2 2017, Texas,      Distillate,     NULL,           NULL

Jan 1 2018, Georgia,    Gasoline,        100,           110

Jan 2 2018, Texas,      Distillate,      200,           190
```

My final table should look like this:

```
Date,       Location,   Product,              PY volumes,   CY Volumes

Jan 1 2017, Georgia,    Gasoline,              NULL,          100

Jan 2 2017, Texas,      Distillate,             NULL,         200

Jan 1 2018, Georgia,    Gasoline,               NULL,         110

Jan 2 2018, Texas,      Distillate,             NULL,         190
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're setting PY volumes to null.. You can do a self join to get the next year values or even prior year values if you prefer

```
update    cy
set       cy.[PY volumes] = NULL, --?
          cy.[CY Volumes] = ny.[PY volumes]
from      dbo.Table cy -- Current Year
left join dbo.Table ny -- Next Year
               on dateadd(year, 1, cy.Date) = ny.Date
                  and cy.Location = ny.Location --if needed
                  and cy.Product = ny.Product --if needed
```

Comment: This will fail because additional join-conditions are missing, probably based on `Location` & `Product`

Comment: Thank you. This worked great. I only had to add one where clause at the end because it was overwriting my CY Volumes from future years and making them NULL.   Here's the SQL that worked:    update    cy

set       cy.[CY Volumes] = ny.[PY Volumes]
from      [dbo].[Vol] cy 
left join [dbo].[Vol] ny 
               on dateadd(year, 1, cy.Date) = ny.Date
                  and cy.[Location] = ny.[Location]
                  and cy.[Product] = ny.[Product]
    

where cy.[CY Volumes] = 0

Answer (score 0):

If you do this once a year and not every hour, then just use a nested query in it.

```
update volumes set cy_volumes = (select py_volumes from volumes v where v.date = volumes.date + '1 year' and v.product = volumes.product and v.location = volumes.location)
```

But I think you want it the other way around : settings up previous year of 2018 instead of current year of 2017

Comment: Thanks for replying. I get the following error when I do as you suggested:    Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: My query looked like this:   update dbo.Vol_temp 
set [CY Volumes] = (select [PY Volumes] from dbo.Vol_temp v 
where v.Date = DATEAdd(Year, 1, Vol_Temp.Date)
and v.product = vol_temp.product and v.Location = Vol_temp.Location)